# jQuery - AJAX calls to PHP - Is this proper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, I'll define my goal here. I want to have a method that makes an AJAX call to a PHP script to load images. However, the images that are loaded are based on a context that is passed through.

**For example:** I want to load a portfolio of images, so I pass the context as "portfolio-images". If I wanted to load a carousel image set, I would pass the context as "carousel-images".

The way I am currently handling this is by using this function:

```
function getImageList(context) {
    return $.ajax("/php/mainf.php", context);
}
```

Then inside of a function (lets say getPortfolioImages()) I have something similar to this:

```
var someContext = "portfolio-images";

getImageList(someContext)
    .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        alert("We broke");
    })
    .always() {
        console.log("Some Debug Info Here");
    };
```

The reason I do this is because inside of .done(data), data will be handled in different ways (loaded into a carousel, loaded into a gallery, etc.). So instead of writing 3 or 4 functions to get different sets of images and then manipulate and use the data, I wanted to create one to accomplish this task.

The above code seems to accomplish what I desire, **but I was wondering if this is "proper" or if this could potentially cause problems? Can this be improved, or done in a much better way?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you don't have any problems, question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . What you are doing seems like very standard practice

Comment: Oh, darn I didn't know that was a site...well, time to copy and paste! Sorry about that.